# Force IDEA to use right source version

Tags: java, debugging, maven, intellij-idea

I try to debug my code in Intellij IDEA. I step into a method, which is in another maven project, but the idea picks and opens older,wrong version of the file. How can I hint the IDE to use the right one?
Thanks

Comment: your question is tagged with maven - did you create project using _import from external model_? Also, what version IDEA are you using?

Comment: A bit more info would be useful: which version control do you use  how are different versions separated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue which I report to IntelliJ some time ago. I believe there is a standing request for enhancement.

The only solution I have found is to remove all the older versions from the Project before performing the debug under File => Project Structure ... => Libraries -> delete older libraries which are duplicates.

Comment: What's the url to the request?